# How to add key and value based on id in object

Tags: javascript

I am having an array of objects, Based on matched key need to add new key and value

```
var arrOfObj = [{
   name: 'eve'
}, {
 name: 'john'
}, {
 name: 'jane'
}];

var result = arrOfObj.map(function(o) {
 o.isActive = true;
 return o;
})
```

`Result` : isActive is coming for all objects
`Expected`: But I want to pass isActive true only if the `name: "Jane"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a condition to add `.isActive`. So it's adding for everything. Add a condition here:

```js
var result = arrOfObj.map(function(o) {
  // Add the condition before assigning isActive.
  if (o.name === "jane")
    o.isActive = true;
  return o;
})
```

Snippet:

```js
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve'
}, {
  name: 'john'
}, {
  name: 'jane'
}];

var result = arrOfObj.map(function(o) {
  if (o.name === "jane")
    o.isActive = true;
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

The output for the above program will be:

```
[
  {
    "name": "eve"
  },
  {
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "name": "jane",
    "isActive": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```js
var arrOfObj = [{
   name: 'eve'
}, {
 name: 'john'
}, {
 name: 'jane'
}];

var result = arrOfObj.map(function(o) {
 if (o.name === "jane"){ //If name is jane
     o.isActive = true;
  }
  return o;
})
console.log(result)
```